# string to date - hive SQL

Tags: sql, string, date, hive, hiveql

I am running queries in a hive environment.

I have a column which has a timestamp but is set up a string in the tables. I tried the following : all of them return Null

```
SELECT 
,To_date(activitydate)
```

Cast:

```
,cast(activitydate as timestamp)
```

This is the how the data is set up in the table:

Appreciate any inputs on how I can convert this :

```
05/12/2017 00:00:00     



SELECT 
 cust_id
,to_date(activitydate)  activity_date
,type type_of_contact


FROM repl_task

WHERE to_date(activitydate) BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2017-01-01' ;
```

I am running out of memory if I run this :

```
SELECT 
 cust_id
,activitydate
,SUBSTR(activitydate,4,2) AS DT
,SUBSTR(activitydate,0,2) AS MONTH 
,SUBSTR(activitydate,7,4) AS YEAR
,type 


FROM task 

WHERE activitydate >='01/01/2016 00:00:00'
```

Comment: Why exactly do you need the date?  Can you show us the full query?

Comment: I need date to filter out the table, with out that I need data for just 3 years or else the table has 25 years of data.

Comment: The following is a work around I am using :

Comment: ,SUBSTR(activitydate,4,2) AS DT
,SUBSTR(activitydate,0,2) AS MONTH 
,SUBSTR(activitydate,7,4) AS YEAR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unix_timestamp` function converts given format to unix timestamp and `from_unixtime` function converts from unix timestamp to given format:

```
hive> select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('01/01/2016 00:00:00','MM/dd/yyyy HH:m:ss'),'yyyy-MM-dd');
OK
2016-01-01
Time taken: 0.118 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using `to_date()` with the date portion of your timestamp in ISO format:

```
SELECT 
    cust_id,
    TO_DATE(CONCAT(SUBSTR(activitydate, 7, 4), '-',
                   SUBSTR(activitydate, 0, 2), '-',
                   SUBSTR(activitydate, 4, 2))) activity_date
    type type_of_contact
FROM repl_task
WHERE
    TO_DATE(CONCAT(SUBSTR(activitydate, 7, 4), '-',
                   SUBSTR(activitydate, 0, 2), '-',
                   SUBSTR(activitydate, 4, 2)))
        BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2017-01-01';
```

If this runs, but is not very performant, then you should consider storing your timestamps in ISO format.  Storing dates as text, or as text in a non standard format, carries a penalty with most databases.

Comment: Run into Memory issues

Comment: As I mentioned, you should either work with date types or if you must use strings then use an ISO format.  You also might be able to reword my answer using a subquery.