# Hadoop Data- Convert Sting timestamp into Hadoop date in SQL Assistant

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, teradata-sql-assistant

I have a fields Name| ID | Timestamp

Timestamp is string like '06/29/2000 00:00:00'
Now I have to filter the table based on date- let say

```
    Select Name
           ,ID
           ,Timestamp
   From Table Where **Function**(Timestamp)= '2000-06-29' (or 2000/06/29 or 06/29/2000)
```

I am using SQL assistant as UI tool with Hadoop HI
I tried TO_DATE and couple of other functions.
Please advise

Answer (score 1):

You can first change your timestamp format and apply the `to_date` function to trim the time from timestamp.

You can convert the timestamp format as below.

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('06/29/2000 00:00:00' ,'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:SS'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS') from table;
```

Apply `to_date` function to the above sql.

```
Select Name
           ,ID
           ,Timestamp
   From Table Where to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('06/29/2000 00:00:00' ,'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:SS'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS'))= '2000-06-29'
```

I haven't tried the above solution, as i don't have environment with me right now. Let me know if you ran into any errors.

Comment: Thanks @roh for your input-
The answered solution helped me.

Comment: If you think I answered your question please mark the answer and if it’s helpful upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You say Timestamp is as string? Have you tried to compare strings?

```
Select Name
       ,ID
       ,Timestamp
From Table 
where SUBSTR(Timestamp, 1, 10) = '06/29/2000'
```

Comment: This will work. even the above query works if I use this-
         Where(Timestamp)= '06/29/2000 00:00:00'
But isn't there is a need to convert part of string to Hadoop date?
And yes "Timestamp" is String.
I might would have named it Date_timestamp.

Comment: Well, obviously the field contains a string so a string compare is sufficient for the case you describe above. To convert strings to dates check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45377124/string-to-date-hive-sql

Comment: Thanks you @Hanebambel, this helped me.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me and we can still play around:

`Select Name
           ,ID
           ,Timestamp
   From Table Where TO_DATE(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(Timestamp,'MM/dd/yyyy 
  HH:m:ss'),'yyyy-MM-dd'))>= '2018-07-10'`